In PrimeNG, how can I add a custom button to the header of a Dynamic Dialog?
I am using Angular v17 and PrimeNG for a project and I want to add buttons to the header of a dynamic dialog, but I can't seem to find an answer. This is the code in my dialog component.
    show(j): void { 
     this.ref = this.dialog.open(DetailComponent, {
      header: 'Text',
      width: '150vh',
      data: {
             detail: j
            }
    });

The only work around I have found is to set showHeader property to false in the component and customize the content of the dialog, but this is not ideal because it makes the dialog not uniform. Has anyone been able to find a solution to this?

The DynamicDialog in PrimeNG is intended to render a given component as a dialog, but you lose the customization of the template as you can only configure some properties.
If you need to create a dialog fully custom I recommend that you use the Dialog component instead, here you can edit each of the implemented templates (header in your case) and can place your current component in the dialog body.
